# Would the spaceship appears shorter in far away galaxy?

Tags: special-relativity

Imagine 2 identical spaceships measuring 100m in length, one is in the solar system while the other is in a galaxy far far away. Would the one in the solar system see the other one being shorter since the expansion of space is accelerating?

Comment: Here is a Veritasium video that explains why the wavelength of light gets bigger on the way from a distant galaxy to ours, but objects in the galaxies do not. [What Actually Expands In An Expanding Universe?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9DrBQg_n2Uo)